# How to image and span in same line

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[image]

How to show Image with span in the same base line?

I am using Bootstrap 4 to achieve this.

```
<li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">
       <img src="img/basket-35.png" alt="Shopping Cart" style="width: 25px;"> 
       <span class="align-bottom">Cart</span>
   </a>
</li>
```

But it is coming like one after another.
Basket is up and Cart is bottom of the cart!!

Not in a line. `display: flex;` will keep them in a line but not in the same bottom line.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem must be caused by either the enclosing element, or custom CSS.

The following displays image and span in the same line, both bottom-aligned, with default Bootstrap 4.4.1:

```css
/* markup to mimic sample image */
.nav-link.align-bottom {
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  padding: 0 0.5rem 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* align all children to bottom */
.nav-link.align-bottom>* {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
/* move text baseline to bottom */
.nav-link.align-bottom span {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="mt-2">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link align-bottom" href="#">
      <img src="https://imgplaceholder.com/40x40/cccccc/757575/glyphicon-shopping-cart?text=_none_" alt="Shopping Cart">
      <span>Cart</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You are right. Same line. But look at my image. and your given Snippet. I want Cart will be bottom align with the image. Cart is center align...

Comment: See my answer above, modified to add bottom alignment

Comment: It is not working.
Same problem as I commented out.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have added some classes to your code, you can try it; it should work:

```
<li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">
       <img src="img/basket-35.png" alt="Shopping Cart" class="align-baseline" style="width: 25px;"> 
       <span class="align-bottom align-baseline">Cart</span>
   </a>
</li>
```